# Help with Linq to Xml query

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml in an XDocument (confirmed by checking in the debugger) generated using XDocument.Parse(myXmlString)

```
<Size>
    <row SizeId="239" Title="XXS" Quantity="20"/>
    <row SizeId="240" Title="XS" Quantity="15"/>
    <row SizeId="241" Title="S" Quantity="12"/>
    <row SizeId="242" Title="M" Quantity="18"/>
</Size>
```

I am trying to convert it to a list of objects declared as:

```
public class SizeQuantityXml
{
    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

But when I do this the sizeQuantityXmlList only has the first "row" in it:

```
List<SizeQuantityXml> sizeQuantityXmlList = 

(from x in xDocument.Descendants("Size")
 select new SizeQuantityXml() { SizeId = (int)x.Element("row").Attribute("SizeId"),
                                Title = (string)x.Element("row").Attribute("Title"),
                                Quantity = (int)x.Element("row").Attribute("Quantity") }
).ToList();
```

This is my first Linq to XML attempt any suggestion greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're querying for `Size` elements - which you got only one. You want collection of rows instead:

```
var query = from row in xDocument.Element("Size").Descendants("row")
            select new SizeQuantityXml()
            { 
                SizeId = (int)row.Attribute("SizeId"),
                Title = (string)row.Attribute("Title"),
                Quantity = (int)row.Attribute("Quantity") 
            };

var sizeQuantityXmlList = query.ToList();
```

---

**Edit:**

Proposed solution won't work if your XML differs from what you posted (eg. is wrapped by more parent tags). Try `Descendants("Size").Descendants("row")` as was proposed originally.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but unfortunately this gives me an {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} exception :-(

Comment: Can you try updated version? I've run both on your custom XML string and they appear to work.

Comment: awesome! thanks mate the second versions works, I am a little tired and I think I may have had Descendants("Size") rather than Element("Size") the first time round - thanks again

Comment: YW, that's what I had in the very begining, but your comment confused me a bit - hence the (as we now know, unnecessary) change.

Comment: Thanks for the "Edit" that works - I don't what I did the first time round... doh!!